# Cut required characters from Text

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, custom-object, custom-field

I have a requirement to cut certain characters from string which is a long text field

The String is as follows:

```
To: Test1@test.com; Test2@test.com
CC: 
BCC: test3@test.com
Attachment: --none--

Subject: Test-123
Body:
Test
```

Now, from above string, I just need what is there in To: (which is line 1) and omit rest of the characters.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class in Apex, you can make use of `substringBefore` and `substringAfter` as follows:

(Let's call the String holding the LTA details as customString for now)

```
String toDetails = customString.substringBefore('CC:').substringAfter('To:');
```

#### Update

Using `Mid()` and `FIND()`, a formula that could work looks like:

```
MID(CustomField, 4, LEN(CustomField) - FIND("CC:", CustomField))
```

Note, `CustomField` is a cached String in your Salesforce flow and should not be a direct reference to a Long Text Area.

Comment: I am writing this logic in Flow and when I try the above logic in formula field, I am getting following error: `The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra '.'`

Could you please suggest any formula here?

Comment: Long Text Area cannot be used in a Formula unfortunately. Please update your post to remove any tags that do not align to your problem.

Comment: I am storing this long text value in a variable in flow. That means we would be referring to custom text variable instead of long text field directly

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of String Class in Apex
Ref: [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

Check [StringBefore](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substringBefore)
where you can metion separator as "CC:" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write code, this installable Flow extension may be helpful: https://unofficialsf.com/easily-extract-substrings-tap-the-power-of-regex-with-findtext/